# Closing $uibModal On Exiting the $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-routing

I am using ui-router for routing in my angularjs app and ui-bootstrap for UI.In my app on entering a state i am opening a uibmodal which basically returns a uibmodalinstance but when i change a state using

```
$state.go('dashboard')
```

Inside my controller it is changing the state but didn't closing modal.
So i want modal to be closed on exiting the state.
i Have written following code but some part of code doesn't work.
please see coding and the comments for  not working part

```
    $stateProvider.state('makeabid',{
                parent: 'dashboard',
                url: '/makeabid/{id}',
                data: {
                    authorities: ['ROLE_USER'],
                    pageTitle: 'global.menu.makeabid'
                },
                onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
                    $uibModal.open({
                        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/makeabid/makeabid.html',
                        controller: 'MakeabidController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm',
                        backdrop: true,
                        size: 'lg'
                    }).result.then(function () {
                        $state.go('dashboard');
                    });
                }]
//this part doesnt work             
,onExit:['$uibModalInstance','$stateParams', '$state',function ($uibModalInstance,$stateParams, $state) {
                    $uibModalInstance.close();
                }]
            });
```

My Controller Coding is as follows : -

```
MakeabidController.$inject = ['$stateParams','$state','$uibModalInstance','MakeabidService'];

    function MakeabidController( $stateParams, $state, $uibModalInstance, MakeabidService) {
        var vm = this;
        loadAll();
        vm.clear = clear;
        vm.save = save;

        function clear () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        }

        function save() {
            // console.log(vm.comparableData);
        }

        function loadAll() {
            vm.comparableData = MakeabidService.getobject();
            if(angular.isUndefined(vm.comparableData)){
//$uibModalInstance.close(); //It doesn't work
                    $state.go('dashboard'); //This is working 
                }
            }
        }
```

AnyOne Please Tell me solution for closing the uibmodal on changing state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tap into to some of the `$stateProvider` events.

I do something similar in one of my apps (in coffeescript, but you get the idea)

```
@$scope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (e, to, top, from, fromp) =>
  @$uibModalInstance.close()
```

Basically, in your controller that handles the modal, you will watch for the `$stateChangeStart` event, and when you catch it, you can close the modal.

See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki, specifically the section on **State Change Events**

---EDIT---

I just noticed that these calls are deprecated. If you are using `UI-Router > 1.0`, there is some documentation here on how to migrate: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events

Comment: i found out It uses rootscope instead of scope.thanks for the answere

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding $uibModalStack.close() in my app.run

```
function run($uibModalStack) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
       $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
   });
}
```